# Panel on Control Focus

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, multilingual

I am working on a multi-lingual WPF app. The user must provide input for multiple languages at same time. This works but it also moves fields below it.

What I am looking for is somewhat like this:

[image]

What I have done so far is below:

```
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  Content="Field1" Padding="0" Style="{DynamicResource ControlLabel}"/>
<Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content=":" Style="{DynamicResource ControlLabelMiddle}"/>
<StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3"  Style="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
    <TextBox x:Name="txtField1" Height="23" GotKeyboardFocus="txtField1_GotKeyboardFocus" />
    <Grid Background="White" x:Name="pnlField1" Visibility="Collapsed" Panel.ZIndex="99">
        <Border BorderBrush="blue" BorderThickness="3">
        <StackPanel Background="White" Margin="5">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Label Content="Language2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="10" Padding="2" >
                <Hyperlink Hyperlink.Click="btnClose_Click" x:Name="btnClose" >X</Hyperlink>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtField_Second" Height="23" Width="280" />
        </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

When the above control gets focus, my second language panel comes up. But it moves my next row controls down and doesn't look good.

Comment: -1 this question doesn't define a specific programming problem, and it doesn't show work done to address the problem. The code that is pasted doesn't help clarify the question. If you have any questions about this, please feel free to respond.

Comment: Tanx Aaron, But i want to create a simple user-friendly multilingual app, now i want user to get two textbox for multi-lang input, i have suceed ed in that but issue is i want that panel to poped out so that it doent move other controlls..

Answer (score 0):

To keep the panels from moving, try placing them in a `Grid`, rather than a `StackPanel`. This enables you to specifically define where each element is placed in the `Grid`. In a `StackPanel`, elements "stack" on top of each other. As contents of the panels change, the amount of space each element takes up in the "stack" also has the potential to change.

Comment: Aaron Thanks Again But I have tried as you have told me to replace `stack panel` with the `Grid` but how i have tried replacing all stack panel that results in it only shows the textbox for second language. and same if i replace all .....

Comment: @wpfoverflow In addition to replacing <StackPanel> with <Grid>, make sure <Grid.RowDefinitions> is defined and the children elements use Grid.Row="#". Check out MSDN api documentation for Grid for more info and examples.